# All jQuery UI effects disappear when I add the last slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get the hang of JQuery UI. So I'm designing a webpage with a form which has UI sliders and buttons. Here is my code :

```
http://pastebin.com/gVZMVaZL
```

The problem starts on line 88. The element  is supposed to contain a slider to input color data (first of three, the others are blue and green). However, when I use the UI .slider() method on this div (the commented out code on line 42), the rest of the sliders and all other UI effects just disappear! Why is this? How do I get around this?

Thank you in advance for your consideration.

Comment: Consider creating a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ so that people can test the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo; remove the extra semicolon after `'horizontal'`:

```
$("#red_slider").slider({value:128, min:0, max:256, orientation:'horizontal'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Max can only be 0 to 255 for RGB values.  There is a good example of how to set up color sliders at http://jqueryui.com/slider/#colorpicker.